# Logically ANDing NSUInteger and String Type?

Tags: objective-c, logical-operators

I've searched Stackoverflow and other sites, but I can't seem to find this answer.

In Apple Text Editor source, they have at least one routine that does some apparently strange logical ANDing between two non-boolean variables. Casting them as Bools CAN be done, but doesn't make much sense. I'm learning Swift and much less familiar with Objective-C, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how they are trying to achieve the goal stated as "Build list of encodings, sorted, and including only those with human readable names."

Here is the code:

```
/* Return a sorted list of all available string encodings.
*/
+ (NSArray *)allAvailableStringEncodings {
    static NSMutableArray *allEncodings = nil;
    if (!allEncodings) {    // Build list of encodings, sorted, and including only those with human readable names
        const CFStringEncoding *cfEncodings = CFStringGetListOfAvailableEncodings();
        CFStringEncoding *tmp;
        NSInteger cnt, num = 0;
        while (cfEncodings[num] != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) num++;   // Count
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(CFStringEncoding) * num);
        memcpy(tmp, cfEncodings, sizeof(CFStringEncoding) * num);   // Copy the list
        qsort(tmp, num, sizeof(CFStringEncoding), encodingCompare); // Sort it
        allEncodings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];           // Now put it in an NSArray
        for (cnt = 0; cnt < num; cnt++) {
            NSStringEncoding nsEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(tmp[cnt]);
            if (nsEncoding && [NSString localizedNameOfStringEncoding:nsEncoding]) [allEncodings addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:nsEncoding]];
        }
        free(tmp);
    }
    return allEncodings;
}
```

The line in question contains the "&&." Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I would say this is a nil check: if both of them are non-nil, the if-condition is true.

Comment: That makes sense and what I was guessing. It just seems so random. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C is a strict superset of C, so the same rules for logical
operators apply. In contrast to Swift, which is much more strict with
types, the logical operators in C take arbitrary *scalar* operands.
(The *boolean* type `bool` did not even exist in early versions of C,
it was added with the C99 standard.)

The C standard specifies (see e.g. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.pdf, which is a draft of the C11 standard):

> **6.5.13 Logical AND operator**
>
> *Constraints*
>
> 2 Each of the operands shall have scalar type.
>
> *Semantics*
>
> 3 The `&&` operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type `int`.

In your case, in

```
if (nsEncoding && [NSString localizedNameOfStringEncoding:nsEncoding])
```

the left operand has type `NSUInteger` (which can be `unsigned long`
or `unsigned int`, depending on the platform), and the right
operand has type `NSString *`, which is a *pointer type*. Therefore
the above expression is equivalent to

```
if (nsEncoding != 0 && [NSString localizedNameOfStringEncoding:nsEncoding] != 0)
```

where the zero in the right operand is the *null pointer constant*
which is usually written as `NULL`, or `nil` for Objective-C pointers:

```
if (nsEncoding != 0 && [NSString localizedNameOfStringEncoding:nsEncoding] != nil)
```

---

*Some more information how this relates to Swift*

Cocoa/Cocoa Touch Objective-C methods which return an object pointer
usually return `nil` to indicate an error 
(compare [Handling Error Objects Returned From Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1)
in the "Error Handling Programming Guide"). So

```
[NSString localizedNameOfStringEncoding:nsEncoding] != nil
```

would mean "no localized name for the encoding could be determined".
The Swift equivalent would be a method returning an *optional* string,
and you could check the success with

```
NSString.localizedNameOfStringEncoding(nsEncoding) != nil
```

However, this does not compile, and here is the reason why: If you option-click on the Objective-C `localizedNameOfStringEncoding` method 
in Xcode to show its declaration then you'll see

```
+ (NSString * _Nonnull)localizedNameOfStringEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Here `_Nonnull` indicates that the method is *not* expected to return
`nil`. This kind of nullability annotations were introduced to
improve the mapping of Objective-C methods to Swift, see for example
["Nullability and Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) in the Swift Blog.

Because of this `_Nonnull` annotation, the method is imported to Swift
as

```
public class func localizedNameOfStringEncoding(encoding: UInt) -> String
```

So testing the return value in Objective-C can be done but makes no
sense because the method always returns a non-`nil` value.
In Swift the compiler *assumes* that the return value is never `nil`
and returns a non-optional `String`.

The translation of that if-statement to Swift would therefore just be

```
if nsEncoding != 0 {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome info, thanks! As noted, I was able to cast both as boolean, but in context, it didn't make any sense. The results DEFINITELY weren't going to be as expected, which I proved testing it in the debugger. What you explained was my best guess, but I was having problems finding documentation (or examples) to back up my theory. I never thought about going back to the C standard. :-)

Comment: @AZ_Coder: What is not as expected and what did you test in the debugger?

Comment: I excerpted the code above and tried translating it into Swift (a mental exercise, mind you). As you noted, Swift has stricter typing, so there was no "literal" equivalent in Swift that employed logical ANDing. I tested that theory and confirmed that there was no way boolean casting would work.

Comment: @AZ_Coder: I have added some more information about how this relates to Swift. Does that clear the things up?

Comment: Yes, that does, thanks! I agree with your conclusion, too. It's challenging to get into previous coders' heads who have not provided much inline documentation and I work under the assumption they know more than I do when analyzing their code, especially in a language I not well versed in (I'm more of a C++ / C# guy). I started learning Objective-C, but changed to Swift as I figured that would be Apple's emphasis in the future.

Comment: @AZ_Coder: If an answer fully answers your question then you can *accept* it by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved (and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer). – Of course you are free to not accept an answer, or to wait for other answers.